# decode PHP extension / show only code

Tags: php, decode, mcrypt, plaintext

I want to develop an plugin and had change some lines of codes.
But I can't get the source code of the PHP file.

Is there any way to show the code before it executes? I tried with "echo" but it won't work.

The Script Use these extensions:
http://www.xtream-codes.com/downloads/extension/x86_PHP5.4.zip
http://www.xtream-codes.com/downloads/extension/x64_PHP5.4.zip

This is a Sample Code:

```
<?php xtream_codes_exec("8F3G9F4IDbYUObGztwhNs0X_Qf3xIRUBb3Zj3V85NQ1SadupubgmlVTjpo8pR7fDH5KuBZ8pDmBvxO78BDsfgLwXV-XhjKNBEX6ebkbcECbISVYUl-MlLsdc_4tOx9ikqJefqKLKPYCrLjBGcoD3R__cDzM6k1UDkwXt8aEUDCerBxFtgf4bF-CJ-5tO4QxnOlEAAoVL_F4DQRqMiYy1LAGJ5gMfztyS2FK8LEV1F26wqYfarL9h6hBNy_22T2Gf2UZZSxVg5EBkaX1VEObSo2QpaBdh47aAWaIT9vZh3ILkLTWcjH5cyqkOhfVrZZ71gD4z3xB7ktmu2yf:VRbruqenDelcZ-YFKPoJhN1ilYu1M3gAjL8gwgDvrYQ02h63ikOQ-28u16DpKF1SVej0gbcjghOKPT8svfhyiW22bzkOyiJv3bDI8ZVLRZcDhLbrGGFEHRk0LErfDb77wz8LpoqstssXmYnOjqwpNOd4HUX-Xaj-LdlnlmvuxIWcPFYC2iAF4YrmCzJV0dM1M5yU8WjxBRq-f851lLvFf_eI0kbz68MEgUtiFEnUnbbKv3ga49NTJffLlb1qG0II-lr8OCA0AUgdNCvkhn8nuaV4bP2zFSfz4_a_YKvQaaeFhZXcwwJ0jxot5ny4mosl5cAWZMAozI04UfziCws0t440pcrmDrX0VLZLy6tVSEDtmK4qE5bqptj2K7:friyuxV2PJrZAfM31zlG-z0hBv5QUOSAKujDADP1pqd5jh9wHtOYUXJr-X4bkfhl4asIMBEkszxNDbgut-qzW4P0IUBWuk3VJyEoHm2TiYwrN2MF_0nvbobBQIKZZEpqJWP6H9s57O2kqP_B-ncMoY9wiKX55Qyp0YhtqQxIv2tqGEdqgygKdTJmlv4AcHnlNWFst3uotNwQb3VlTuKBlIE7XBZrPGqUpRV0jVqcUnm10Cwyo1iPRSfMAiHKadWp1Mj22G5C4LYQK_jfCK6R-cE4ZOajxmYWCx4-sIUUeph9Z2jFYcOYY-Flfvz5qiaGpoaSWTRQBXpMhAu5AdYEHJaAZax28Z3yS6MKCf30LuA9sghwhpXtKYEiWdhF6zfQ8JfGpz-5OLOkxWvnwBuvjWxsdD8qR5XG2D5qT_iKJzsa9Lut_EhobmuRIn2Bifn6lY7ktJmGRk7rGIAqKBL0D8oBJjH6sWKxthoev0jCaRBhjfpxqpyQz1OCsmA905Z5tjcKcmtpUPUKM:J4ZRrd_imyl2GSvv7ydctiYGRTXRKCZ5533Xt_zWKXoQZjaj-eFeIgy24Lg6fdFCyF72uFEIwllfOH02sIKDdgSJdrItgbm3X9aLt3TPLdCnO8ycegEKjA60QFYyn01Zewz0i-KKpdOXHjODRX0010yflFMGSKIN5m7PDPJKIEcvjIi_oUAQhVFISeSCB-_-OJuQWvaa_kDeMqMxcf5klJHyCnqGvYek9KSRvK0qfXRpaBsTSgmrmihAAW88hNfNzvSNoBEFmJi1Q81TDyX0RzlhEiYO993cFVHCRjpd:TBDnUCrNCvcS6ZdHnPtJ8awwEIRivxXCP2j0dirOQPP6XDnextD-iDU847-KDnr4DmTNbc6jlYVd7PPsEABcvMmoLcb-DaaGQgpyDFD6F3ROSiQy3uX6WLITuZYd5tH1AWbm2C0skRaWMWBqAFmRf9W-mJVSan0orHkR-0_xsp2vGzgM0kElaqLMPg6nNToQQcgfKe-qN5suMzmJWLX5CKS1FuYKPSjdaxH-Q8u7XbQ0F92iKezd3t2EWGPDLd-W_2BOM5R6yE3tYo8MEcXJLMm1-D8YyZ52p9S_B1xNG7aTL-f6YnXKzfJggdgmXd36Bn9qKqq7JqDlUz9hm0durcK3GOAS3h-uAehG0ZaJsx4gVR2JsVhCVsBiiIChJLmlGUpOORgBWZZGy4XiUEpw7sVRJxxrnKJcrGnySCIs0Sy4RgF1_hQt91N5i-kkEkDcSuXUmvqW0r82zTUipVU2rHo9X2QfWDkY5ncSPwQvu9xzqHkvW3ECemRUd5ZYiJqtevayeRfi3fJd1FogDbjCmHmUvS-jEjhWNAfbBphf4p3r3oQelIGrsjzv2Mtc2fM84XvEcxcZxr7Vq6Hq0Qsv7i99-ufXU2Il3tqJzA0dSvFbIaGDvKGQlbYu73wHzuLOKT0s7s5C1LzEf3AHPLsJTuKH0XGzzZL4DwQsBqndr1nUdpsuGW8jzpsMicOeR4Mdx_pENAJzz9x_AVmhhInf_Lcp4Qx4LbQnbU4rPJRrD3USi-e1LNL_JJpV2B7Gu7WTacBpsJVdjxND3m-OAlW5hyejzWKv72Cjl_U0P601mWawUS5ULk-Lhk1kupO-4Anm_xIH7RpkCvGcg4jiOTAxch77a34c5czYqE-COHuf7nKg5L1d5GoOV_fCpJLkkrLAGMFxMkx9zk_O7FeXkQuojin9ciUDexTVhaJas2aiWFnvZooM_lUk818KYA6j_4yMq5JUE3P-xSemjxe9P9DrM_ivUklExkh_fLMGNKET_yIIUmZy3UdGYnVQxKQzjJneeyuc9MVKVGgCpCFYoLEBddskVxTHCSbrutXBGzr2NtXZTKjO7xsBULh7M4t41JfxHnoawle8Jr92QEwRfmP-nakC-Z_DB4gjfdfzQMn92CTX1QZSM0WQVSEbg44yGnF2DMv9EhwoFalzuX8n-CAcnJXmuO6BoLM-BFwcSqWK_DfiMyIGzZJbfuuhzN_JfSnbyBciFn8i5JnZwfflyy_yTUdI1M7BzEsD7wQrhA4SUDkVaPGVcjvGMtiLTgL8BCszilQXVVh61k0T5iwrS0DkucdXnJzbWqwdXsrB8n3o1ubxukoMOJ36pNxOa0XD:T_jMFz1dFl-tXBAvTethLC4Ajfqjk-279Vy3rxrI4-6V4UshKYTGvt1dTVcDI2XglloBGX4nAGLuqYvKANF7FptJc_zvOA69fDGV_HmGu3OZwFc4NwPEpz_M6PRPg-QMqkiqzpQU6JomPNFpcCtuIu3w8OgEEHoqRhW2hCKlaf-UyOMiv5RuY6QxJoN5rSIMq_FlA35VXO2euyq9p23ADjw3XuBBID2vD2f3GkF3LVeX3mIFp-oXElTGDdKZbGewk6QEd9lflNOtjYjynxu4B7Tr848HfeSVRJUjOw7e3CxwSjExMSZcfuPAIobf66uIDMlX0l7aoZO0Mgs5Ws84sWOi0K:sasJZjrMCHEtC5inYwCDC_0AxmcwoCgviVyyZld6k_2x7Vre6KfI71gxni2VzJLyQwoSxKufz5iWQ7kRdjBDyngngx9xIj9pvQh7_LO9R4q7xyRu-3TjLtKMhp8aaB9vR3xZo4fMFUFK944cTFCzbZQrkv8Uzs6lmoF9GcoB2JCWuYmLZC48qV37S7QS06qx5HYHoYEgFoBKwgg7ZiTy12XdIPZ8xd--_Fsv5OJpaXdsve5Xc1nPf1OeVna1b5MTsV4RRwHHXX5Z4JyQId30LdJm9UHqtN83Y8NMWSD2mC06P-jeJ3_PIJK-Eo6IOihTZOW3yVOpjL9BeX2xtUHPuEQlUKJcxOEs9Sh_f-iYyAfn6FF7c8uxwngp0iERxfcXt8vT5K9jhowBMtNRHQN9qn6UCGYnSQuxGmvCjQY--syfk3IGWwls-wEiw5rOCFh5_jxNN2tedT1V57-ItUHvJC4O3iykBN6e6KuR4TDg9Ht7cvO2Ql7Xut7K4AVbNwyOpiQTi5Hj80teUHsXdbRF2sDVD6BQT6J71lJue-U-nGbBP7CUEaT13OTX7WDp50fX0ppXm3yggDCdVNtuQi8QNqFl2wK-FAFdqnZikvuhNSOER8Wj8axh6WTTF3Dl9hIEAg2qxLSVTHIuTHXMOXd4235Wy0CkU40gLycY40O7euDUK4vQzuwY9sV3TGl2RpCxGouSmgsdVK5BqEiNtr1tR7YKJhf4-jIumkb8_s1G8_5p0rCeR5U4BCc__i4UNbGrfwFh1KbyMfTSpRH_eIxiGTEcFAVHeiFsNHcKulPQ8R9s5U0x7P-fb5iHn_NXtDPK8UCRLdHD7U7z8DPtu1v8reDSLfFIImTQiYeZhlnB1-5Mnfp1SMaJq4ewSkUymq1Kqiy2wzoQ_Q990U1wkZCsmaLGGl8E2ywO573b3xaaCyfECqSkom_9LMcHl8x-5bGNtt__4Bt3lS8zVsWCCaJvbsEOwBrIXcNHdACNqO6QHeQCs3qwX_s6BS3un6jGJLy8gZE_VjPKuHj-8R6GFWX_9mxlUjakO2BL1MlKPNPVHSZBzkjtQPsuD5SsUxw_mnyJ3R6clj-d_Tg1GNFgtiC6XefZpTs2DUP-st9DwHXtKG9ZIHTb20Ct9uBiGZSzAr2iTk7p9L786B5pcZ6YyNznGJArek-tveu3qIJT7rXMfaQT47V24s1qgUOj8BtUvnMxQlFAhkUF1kYHoBrH8265B33XMttk8PwqtM_zY14ezziEgs_7oqjzdRHw481lrY66dhIXylXu9KATkoRZMxwafftQAHEoN5sGmr03bPSNRHjkXQVxzwDanEZRJYN5vjt4N2mTYk3r-GZBQbKM1R3lRgFc3yky1ro880IpkgCMXVoV_9lHdVYt9gitRvhdP9W4lzoj6Ch6fb8RuiQxKJjouKJgbbmmrVO6JkXbJX4qr2RbGgVyQPCPGVB2JmLapCj_sC4Fs-E49ThOmYZepYkLSot0wVTssBG0Fw_YJTaysaoUJ1OVKxqjq9X3YkhztUr1y5ddGL571RwUPjXZIwuOLfTtrpChJyRTJvu4mZg_FaxLC_MK55-Bg9HNX_76ldRqmV5SMhvRHTcD7TYT3VwMm_cS7FZZirEZnnhS6UEQnyNdtyMFOHXn51Y2tDW8zapZbsP9WkaZtD900ikW6Eo7bFXt-ScwlWsrhH7Dgy73sF5iUGZGMn8YLzYb8g2fmoacIktKXRaoDdm2mbBb__2dw39Q2lSUk2fQbttJgC7HEH9LDMe1Y0TdGfe_2jWZ1WAQfiiz-vU0pRG_kL460gASwFbf8ur85b1OnG6-97K4JA4DotZ4laP6RB8JPifN_wbNl60Vtq1A2gbBmn8jYx_XYBxLOySHSkN0tpkZ6R1Vigy-9O7oHHEso9NqNdas7lXxzqHLUGge0yBlYYDEeWpPpJxKDLebJwGATl6TGB13qxSraqrfEnZMyitI1NMYUHBwlOElMRd1c:OR4ghpR_jhBtgaWgQqla-8gy5QSrpI-MVlLxz-u7Yjy54ZQ2oT1J2Kh-uUF1vc4U8IXYrYKKuX5PKrPYhU1Vn_U3jggbKPjrEoV0VP2rHyzx47Dw0M_ela42-wRc5JYeeMi-V0yzPUthy3ukRuf-ltrGzQ8X1JxLtQb-5vlf86AkCI-WGaWf6s5HGtSnXdT6tbjy2mQZblGnhcra2UiifbJMvopiFGRejOiEfziRoXDbDlkbLqHqK1dYcyBsyAHl2Jg5XISVYA_yeCO5RCbUOmoxqIi5IhTB_DQw8SiHltSeDcFML8aD6d3GxCM0tzEWg0ugr3GqlxRYM22eNNFjlT_HL_wLKVuggSL23sFqeDqPD27msRrz49ped4poGa9p0fbmJNns7RjBOg4ogu7cIWgwAOkpeAht92couXItFRpXw_CXGIVgtuN8jg92nlJwo22BlXXKMkGYXPP4UmgZGBkcfMCb_79GQiYa77PhqZVuu_K1WAfWpMBOYGWcO30IWpdocHeVrSXQlKlFfNA005g2KQPiVFbirkUFgzArovSYo5358LAsE4g13bE-exr626Pz01cNZWeJiOlj953NvRzOz5i9is2tCzCWshzpxtdTF2xA1DQQrg2Gfy3ntJ1H_7_1x8Nijsy3HP_bfiMbFyeGeWc8VjiTstpTNO6mp9zlqxVqiADdJgu8NCImOmgtFNTtKzYf4TyJV2NR306W3UOLNCtBSJ8SDPQKrQUpcs6BBIy4khsednmxBWCE8CEDv4K6KC2K9lV0WHp5s6V1OE-nLPyymDng-V0Qy0g2B3qjSHO6IeWGeZuSWXoP6EwVs87rXzedtoR73HrN0-rE8JAf4uWQkPZwLmgDudh0JSuPz9c_H2v3qqu6eE_E7yDGMe6N4taPtv02G0FWlGLETyKIhFvQai1FOEse1MMIpPUM5rDIVtdfNSdN0QvVta_uv0vDsD0bi7aXR_PbiD5BeZ6_w1pOwO1F4qxiXQAbpEJ7dPOnFVjtuJ8-HvxgoO0RQEoppTyzAt0XhNfFhK-D_qxYAug1f1QLuNeu00OYmnnMY2w8Z-Oq7Q2aWIsO5zt7DKz1BfCB1LlU8390CkfmxF98BiG4-RWxMS5iHvQpou6FQ3hb1BThxWLb3xUM0bzjki7yTP_zEP5GP3OfpGcb-5tFfBNH4A8oYCFo1FzgnmNERwCMks2FVDvJ9NkXbH8XmVrycYgrtcDfjL_r4QlE-7bZy5Wswtv-2Aiv0rttQ8Nl9LA6Zw2i8oL7RuEAx6CdHA5vue7XKwq_2Z2qDj_Hkk5kIrcrlxjBEmiAdimUJ1giel9AtgJf9CQu3H0NQHyZwhQ2LPETuQYU4EbPDTcLOV_Y9YEKjp1OOcALMLknPnnF0mcl1Ib0adVMMlLSllXEbS2oYarEAc5HmpfZXK5EurH3u9CSHIGNhQKAftgdF3mwqlLRVQKHK6UfF7ZNkGLBViZuNQRFGrQDPCbvGgKILF4CO8yPnSJpcjQEm:cQG4FZN6_NrRNJhptKLMOq9re26xLz3X5Jiu6iQzq9nHPOt1NMKG-hNT506sdxldiSVn3jzYIp8Ad4KHxIOlQVJiAdm44Nqvekki8cR9rMf__n0olZ_Pghpmvzx4u_bMwA75H_ueKWuo9iECBEOoEBuUZLO1h3e-Jn375dP59xuCOjauVxWXtHroCoTeKh5BxJEdbeCt5z4m1uFyPiAoi02tl8N-r-JjVuZQIq95HXNiJjsW1lriOHR8YT2F4SF0thLQwlaL6aDsNvxD2dPDO92Yxlt9Kblxxpwhh2NoSwTIQQZEfI5yN6FixLtSPA21VnKWRJjT:v2rs6vPevzZD6Bw7Zl5VHwZff6nkBq-FcbhL3KXl4aknt36GzlZ4uwYoJQMzd1Zi8Wn2miSj2w8RO2ncFN1yTd61D89THIQNLq8qPUU8UoBe7C6kYsDbz8jPPh8Vt5kUC9KAImvEQD3BuBHiUyA0:iQ52CxZZbZ3o9tMf-DX8zZYGerpZxr-0-3eYnlgz-OS7iKuRJYfHHnGZENTE2BdK4bLz30tAtHAo0TAanytCLghUvd-AXHo1FgnDouk4dYU5JrgteN98Cg8dg9cYwe9cBVF99x2OdIdAFIHTQr5IZ_J7mleGz9sxUn8-P2v2Cq4srsVdjya2QkzcryoTwtKeVB52XAUwVLlX9_dKf6kc0BRHkZq4OTtARtn6LbMNx2Z85vc9evbQ8u-zrFI6R2s6DURn6YSKkOAL9jUTgn8AvJQMJRR5uL5QFKu69NY7InuF5lCSUCSFtEa2tEI4jGWE-jWYSeOeB9t4FBXvG8ksaW1oY_PSt8rqkN5kiKYmWdambnp6gVguxyC35R31bWfX6B6RrAtJmKGyq152JlkIPTjiKtvspvOEnI7FjSvzv81xGjilP0EwIBCvvIy2MQqR:jmESHje841t26aNLR5EoPv50nbh2MGQ7XLjdn9OcmgVOWJzBbWrAVbRjV-m4mQXsUxVCsdJYDZaD1A2A4FkphgIBqF4nKD9e0-9W3233l1ylp8I3GORFFKr0joI4eY49Dq3HjncpmRMnbJQABPhuKMwnc80DsXn1Cdfsgc1irrZg8j7pNHP4oPGCElMTubeEILbfDroqQku07967e00s5ncQtjAT6ATpWCmQP43UWxGsqvwH7oMeN6mTZbZ3nYTdc53n5ENH6jysSkLCtpTYj92BNFoqqc06rr9fD3:aXkR44lbr3bsUxvv1Wmpior3Kvf3e3DW1NmKfaoWLKQmYOeVlqywWCh9GsHhtNakRssztyQKPe4If_Qtr6OEYKhq2HVJmnEenLC9N6Hp5OgMg64xKHL1pDEoSuVL6wNRJrDjl0-XgM170u6oGdIkhZ4qTZC9RAsGwaOqyhYlUu0ovDikWVIUSW1ONDx4PuFtz1sokTG_jTjxs4h6idbKUFFyhzmzBIJm1MPbpDuWxk5UgnC-QMBl7OlLR2YxnhcTURDFDa3NeG8YvQVoDaWrV1jlKNWXufdmXf8tqyulzckXEJVq73PANx3KIFyX3HWu3oHUqvMM2pEfW0d5OXxkfP7XgH1Z93lV5eaIWlctRc_RZMc-vGYnkEyHGuNUlvl4uFGNztC3fHvTgkLZQLi9NGS7kXRg7t_a5vVxVue8Zc6HMOrqoQM9i1rAaJ1swOVm0Lh_aYwzdERKQ6nPoyIhB2PClIR2wRTfGY7aTjZcaTHqEJ0aczdrV7yjZj91bTFLuRKRRnAGuciIxCnRKGSoDlQWFvb6Ljl5iUi6LOvv1_EjDpPSWf1TNN7sgIcDeG-MhwlDU3Q5Z9u2JsTQt3QuBIftTtaxEvd9Ls1j9xYhiLoM_HgssIPsVTzfUbyyMvXrVv0xtRxsLbzdjnfeZar_jeYG1S-vmgTzaaDMGww2RgDsS6ekJnL2HO6ixf2KHdSBokUKh40PALmFf0q2ZcnW4zVzoi6oMOUyaqADQlCG2DBrR-ZfkKsPPTejvDz-7ITsLZje54j8S0DdprxDV6NVSh6tklzglT2rT-4ToheIuHOGb6fAyuKh_nL8IJYilyXYmiR4NcVatgDdYIzK0t48LOfUgszwFirI7kevskmS1EmJTN7G0MT5A-o-Mw3U2AFtE-HwRVCmtaIvesqQ_xd3eIab-Aya0BjRSJLIlUz3zlaVHiIlJKO40spfahNDXDkd1FEIbfc3qPirJDfJmFggj8sf4VDEkCyE4zZwu2QEdBMCtOf2OqqKjaNdtBZez_nKLYZuTArxcJT4b_-tte3KH5U4acY_91Cc8CuDQBSB00K-SGfye5pXfz2i1RkAJFkBnZV5hQs93mKQ2HPE583eJVB8wsB1dYRAGQhfSaXQkRbXW4fYRkSCj7EPKPkIKB3gp6IuxA8j:fhs_bMVJ_Pj9r9gquLK7FXY8mtkHBHJqJBCrLTkeNO8Cr18WHo7UqxCPPq2DitNwWpMcXPTuwIM5kMssN36SytA2TZeagdtklpWLS2DskkX18KTSzrVH8xOTVBbG1NpJY89tTPo_omYWWFhW2JU2hShdmI696BUOmos-RjAcunnBEdEuWVZ3m0UwLVV64RhSKEYZAw0AUgdNCvkhn8nuaV4bP2zFSfz4_a_YKriyuxV2PJrZA2LJCSuDrsxwY5LB6GwGQxWxi4jxNQFFeyVUk9ZUmAUbq9yA8a7nlydk5MlpyQu-z0_uuN6lGRFGMI6UC5Ablr9LhJnXDNGluCsf0ZkGRLh7fIx1oCHdkSvgU5DzedDInkdc2ImOxbWWuLauzq896_NkPoHDtmXlUfBl9_qeQGr9FdtX7t5KjcgWnl7VCsXJM6GMIhF-VYBrdY7EQoqC9cYeOQ7N5hXfwf5h5SlsyPN0Ek6q6anEn4dBc7v2ur4QrJZ7tTy5UO93oqzKMvgzAGFiXIpuSZ5pnnsf:0vH1850hME03h7HcGO9hb6GwzU7iSq2gHsy1T2rznrNHsw1UMDP-ChKgGhag4jXAWmYi6GHW-UujuDxSsjiWrFCqVy5_uR1zYiY7FtZa4tq7Orz3r82Q-gcO2ZeVR8GX3-p5AavxyhWi1XCeeG5KZdOF1cS2KMrcufn5Zl0T63F0cAMozkMaRPqv5fMatLlwzWljwlEvBKribWbmlLDJ30djJatFCc42-rX9CxmPh1JU4oKLPGng6_uAiKsYpMvN3gPw_cPFObJGLw6uFaARGMlQlWf3FDzA1hGCXftrvVXnO7_F6xDYfdvmnc7eJ8QVmUX4BAIAN4jVLyvUIQhIORI0Pb2j5dYp2NKBhZQMPWPfNiMd3UFS3Bf8mYLxDf_rMj-ZL0ksYugemK-L5y_4RdqodjwfmQM5eerQFi4aQQbVttxkADqd6YazF48wMcogv9IHJkMhDFFfJp0PvWOP8JTU3QixAWXX2fW06ErwAjGNKUlRGDvRoOy_6E3bnXT9HY5-Bzjg9q9IxyQNSC9a36N2iufWHYwQS0RBwwhSmXrok_nQzeS8CfGSzCwz2ObiwMq08MXk0sWMb7qOKCcRmH5M6lE25P0JOK3yadcpO8PAKVKUhGooBewnFFJZ33IjodljFaGCJCBf5CX36PazkMXjfCJwz899JNI:mG6co2S6AApTSL-nxXAxLPpyQPfuhs3S7ObG5pe0OecJlGCloE8XwvRv8mLqIiSjpZZknDPUxBjgOcyBm5a13XTJXkwSB3tNZLeUQyhfrK0AFFmJlqdAxZf_sx9IBltrHnEP0FK7UgUGI10jJGOtR1JGKpzoF0ZC0mipdqK7Lpo2-y0TZ6xCz07DM0AUgdNCvkhn8nuaV4bP2zFSfz4_a_YKriyuxV2PJrZCgKdiwXs5xIHvmf4UVSGLX72hOjK90tMMYLlpWzix1rwiq8thyN9okHHLMzrMAs7aHNprUWOEcO9pkqFGl6G7F1S0nb9-NnhgXwMvD8kHO7O6Sb3HtSTrTVKKH51JBvF4pzh74a3__rtj8A-MVQYKN3jI4DoKUBXcaO_DHCqlFwWfKV92aMbRPU1_IKFlumlJTOQDoERkyVLxneGdw082ABQ7K5PLp8w2Nb3nPEUKGhAdkqDS6WXfHa8ydU6D3vUZStWZUaJUBxMVXNKdk8delxpQniJBjTK2MYtSK_bGn7s_IaurLV0PCY-NOuxoBn6GzEaendHQWW4jW6WsXAScM0zue4lLOHiuKf5cecnFcN9NKts7FebcMRcNVQZFYRXgZr0m1juGwpr27v5Qwu3fhiUuqpi:paMUb2NCK93--46hmEYVpaGTz6V0DsbLOmchF__9i_-379sg29fcU0GKHSfCluOKHDIypPDoAmQ6MrkDJUts9fXtCY7-K8tCqbN9OETvkukVA_MOw9sbMowl385m-d4nVy2FXWqORk7uA5xw-jipiwUX20kQVRZA0DmSv4up5ROpEI9ULc79LGpIRrEm4wlcJqraN9C0JHMfYdAQfPvmHLs6u_GPTd1tk0QvC5r7uxdnolIAbgem0h-kpkfjF9puvkVD20sl3suPmgtKc4e-Gt__67Y_APjFUGCjd4yOA6ClAV3GjvwxwqpRcFnylfdmjG0T1NfyChZbppSUzkA6BEZMlS8Z3hncNPNgAUOyuTy6fMNjW95zxFChoQHZKg0ull3x2vMnVOg971GEQha7e5afm5KhsjgDwPLzJLz8LlGsgsi3WbkcenZRFYfhDcURFl30Zjr68PeKjuq5CmWUBTJUnZY08wDlzY7qlosJeTB:2CWAKc64p1kC4OQ6ye3c2GWKzQcsjVMSi2tFQSIcL7NGSi0iXoWhT8kx1kb71LvgfGqToTCGTJzcbdb45hJK0FnT5mKq8_kLre-CubS7oDL5VpwPTIvxxbloi3U_RwDhFP-KhVZaMqm5Mm16S4xH2Me11DBmQUwjxUjQWmLYgBuRLb_kH_Ml2VVJ9jsffowzfqBFFd67qGSC-EiUK71vndfqaPFkg3JsQ5vOazyobJ_Bd21tMf-ND3k-qzDRmhwriDc0Z6XLvgDs6lSLYy0dvn4BNlVvx9htCRCU9BPxK5KMQkUhFxs-jPLJtV7rGGvYfp__KmuWl-X_m7pr7Lc1f8XDqVCLVwHtwORWp4X8URd9ybe4wsHKQsFntFvdPg6poRIJp0lRvAkJ0Tu1gN1ZPvgfFndr8UQkwPl40FHzCS:zZIY3qWXxpARk2UVQ42XzLSWVAVzkXqSVcxcXsEwZYQeNv1hg26Zd4WY3fY6O78PkN8cEoi9xPOgC5pwB5MRfuPVKfh6Qfw7jPGYwe1_PposV5cKIjSjHOq8D8ybWz0ZsyXixEkV5XvM8X_KZE7F2u-PL_HeFiBnfnAm9Qty7VW1gmA_TrFGd_tN3JVljyKdWiQ-kCpcKvqr_5m-Db7_UgwyJt6s1xmCkHNTN5VnYFQhQ9zcLMxnu2qrvvdA0JdvzShwS9Cq_MnGRHXYtkF4IGCNWZeAT3dT6Ela1DCgvkpK9xgAaC8dOeo2oBzbsyOWV3Vcy5WEGebCDihqRAeQOwc9OHXZfkjSFimzPTsg1KzQBQ3Hy6QE1M:AXFgtAiSvc9e8p5gcueIZkeXF8eNIulQan4snxTtzOVJuqG2CKM_LQgwhqlWerjRfcY6GDhiylH-93wSp37CkuRitRbmCj0o3WsR_kPLu120NBfdoins3d7dhFhjwy3flv98PsU3gC7pGOfS2MlOW0X3AQ_YR9qe_iJPEYLJDWJpSZqmVamr7B_MF3fOWdpUme8jpSQuRv9NJpP7dmq08RFKhHbpgxKRM5JFPcO0OKiuMAonIykOcQKzP0XDRMgAPDkySNR4u_MUUn_Vr6V48N5JUAjnoJc5CmwfV4_UvhHA1Z91S1Y1f6PZcNcQtOjgmkhOe_Vz3kGg9B5RkM1z37dJ53itfp1GdhHizI6rCNk0Yz07TexnUoKX8SrBIaXOOanhwA0yUYhQ2rHtUhrRsrMH_2EBTU5KlAe-bJ58Qoec7uhyIgqwU21DfomR0enRJxh0TCG2nHTgeftRzuQF2Qt-YSIwBUthZXF3tM6nefcXM3WsgIhWFsV8mbaboTZ5-PhVZsT4O_e3qMJbN6jXizZ8HTn_KN5e7wB90zEFuTKmapg3fSFs9mwcKB51hUcl6dyqRuIaQ0R4UvMfmXMHz3ZF4X0kULiITAkcUH0iifQeLo81:D-BcbACHMS99Wmg6keWu3sj9ASn6Xz1rALgxsLiBFqCUU36u0qC2PMakbMmhog7-43ZwIuf6KKLnDsduRGWscdA4iAk8stxnr4buYPMpOU5JgplWJUUhDjSnpV9KlnuWa1bI0LObXph17A8PxdxoDT:Dljgt_WHBC9EFrrtRyL-zJS4U56464OKv3Wud4lold02HsmoA1wJGBq5NHqEFZxgLiyVB-40xn3DMCys7E4y7TltQ41UCvWOI96wwdSTjbul45mW3WwhAM7AHd64CZKKEA32dYHZy_aLOQ1hP0ErPGkedVxQFLU0ZB8CmiuYptMaGCXuD6JqJuKi7OVbCP4J5PVNU-8z9S7a7sin_qYHdkFZWuyOG1cvnvqkvqlohD1viUu6szpa3pEia20tzOe682u6tY7oDAFPGcoInnwhNf7wU9D32QpvcUkBBCfzEDF9L71bA:xyHAJXH5KOgw7M7EbPpXbg73RCdVoQJ3PV8vuXAx72d-9Nmu8HTmo_7H1Y9YnXkfU7BGeL42kiVSUsLo2TjzjmA3sWfK5vEkCbMA6s_tvz4Ryu1j1XMCvqxT1KSRb1AESQ5cLoAetCfL3gSeG90NvmieCRXvD-2Kv8eiyIzTz2mruyu2MnqsmgCyMHV0hrijj2CbLAbjO7rOgNIdzbvxHuTkBvhlmngpHGZ5dnVPxZcWiG6QnT-YWEyM-2RjgGVzLLB2lhW7SkOkZuac-syvzDCAOq6A8KHeGp36t1bm2NDSqei7GpwjsZXAwpvBM5WWw3Shxz3-0g0lHy0MGpBSZXs4ewiOPvGDfqlix49N_CWSm4-xxXu3Gkwrn_11tl4KhcnFhoBTpDyE3Dva7YOqeUz3tKM_iKmwczV---E2fDU6N_oObaKc2GDyTPyLUjeFnohEdcSKdlMrZkR0NsMaG8rf7gA7M4OkM2bu3CZUD-00kwjqxlHwAgP9AFI4O_5CrhCjX24PrGsC1Fh4jLs4BYDIMtoXmY3AEWdXeOmV9tQhzED52P4EmAQqH66yhQZIE3kQtQP0oXDDWC34uBPmlEl1fTHIhcc6lSwl99he0R1JM3l6CKXKf1uC9VJ-ZfhMn8FHIiPRDL2kU01e-Ck_-qn7DXxv2K_k5GuR1HzMMuzeA1Ubswq0zbpWARdjILJIfQLQAgIpmCyUFkExbS1xCvGMJpghh9hAfiucq8F1h4TrCCbthcqNJ4R89Pxq6DbdFpEfgjyaPVhBCK:JW22N45RRtOIGzLptSs1PDdIIJ8Pz226cYVWRVgaHs2kZNLOopINeAemwDV8Q9VJRHyZhsTjrrzivSmMFN0C6Ax_G9v5hIbm2N_G65jtCZ7eYHzGHNLXvdP3xwaKzC319H5-PLdCMrcqRaNQ8Al2CI9RY6ysZAjb6g1bduIbXD467qpA8oh7_liitkaSVju6ZIoyLaQeR71ozIEewklY3kKrJ5lL68cjsODSAyQsFkfeJSsYQXNDMBpaiSDaZx-olu8v6B-F2j34tslXJnGLuuYJYdxQhyh1SXgy4Iki3iVkjp_LUP6A-vwy2p8jcO9khUvEch2T9fMZglcV7e5wRg89NNkymSLA8hl6_Gf3mzfiF7ecYkWgVvEV_6qTgFzKYqVJT1li-Hey0dYy_e22XdYA9CR3r_oQZgd2NpDzv8U9XQEzhyW6Db5uouqTiK5IDwqCJn4Kt7L-X0kmiwH_cI6xGUhip27fR6CMoISrsJoVxdW9s7yg7uKReCDx4Y61x87ad60uA1zvRnQ0VZm89IhCDYdbTr2a93Gs0zx9M1aEH6r31hW5OU1MzFbLbmW6GdwSnf6:5mIPgwXSWdZThNcRRu0IVoGcAKaayOqHqEx95XCRjrxfgHMI0CX5EhRBIZZmXZLlzd9ErtBxT8mFtFtS2FUVIFZkdvgl3X:Ihk3PhchlYM_psno8KGaZIrTmcsgE9b4vR627sBvAjgdWQanMH1JFKGymme_DQ6OaEU42uLOga4xWAr_YyN7kXXrPdhoyRMb5YU6PNe4o6lc6u9BE4-7hzf_drru4-WFsE8ckzkHzvqTlIDi5M-j2zpUMQOw2ZaQaDf4yW40EPrSN6ee3mHDUSkR8XRsrcZhSB9slYzrJIhRBl6bxlpja-wkjYJRp0OCKuS1sXhH57EuI_dW0xS7kSkUZwBrnIiMQp0ShkqA5UFhb2-i45eYlIuEOvMZ0emRu2swn0t5XNNKlHfkUImnioIhV_LX6pea6eY_2lFilZOQasq10u2MVtEWESvcCnZK48Z0uN-eP-iZBVAgtvf67XNYQaof7YjmTHQvkvxArHDCkO1XxB7YwUh9IeO3ikWPbROxZ5j9o0l8b8I7OypW9hZacPLCA0uIeubF2c3m:EVAHVC9L3a9AEfmv0WJztIs3pAfmP4A2RtRVYcpOFBTPo6se_ZSmkh_f4ebSV9JonqykDHu-obh0LILQBSB00K-SGfye5pXhs_bMVJ_Pj9r9gquLK7FXY8mtkEDoAv4olrvaTxpThzd1nTMB9l-YoZLX4HXUQJBcvDNAXeYiWINYVvJSgSQmV3v9jsvttt-4us_5SUHYNYMbHkbXpEvhX3FQf1ADlC5l8QYjJzGxpIFogbB0rckKuJO8tqcL4IbBL8YtF61WHzCKjZ61JgUd9UBnjnA2jVwBUY:XiUMqNejHb-CWCFKF3DmFOE5tjJbDXW785qR6EhdgoHmVWfF4kP_R_gCXj_Sp2wK982QQGs4U2EJWwe62V7B0X8pYLnSCar4fjzPH741vqUTOn8aypNNVKolgtsoWGn2FZRbnij0CljVHZTVC3YRaBV5Q_jd57A7I61_FcwkSg1mVNoZOlr4CQ2iAQpPPzq17dGaSJA4KHTpqpCetJddkN3hDjLmws6gYglDO4bfOujVOMlqh5ApEz4Wg3BmxL4QG3XM5Uz1vQ1JAjZ3-C9WFPVXu-bUCtqgpV66mEe67hs-SZCUkvICazdCSiXUF3KmZSydPxYzSydjZ464Pak8tjTJOwjuRlv0pHNGhCNu4v9UwbHQJYRsfzgA0L2o9dRxJYhP-wshM6AlEZkdTlVg9ylG8uw9udhUfl-SEMX2P9v-U8wR6_b5jZl-mgulKJPSuIQyQicvQm5NxDzdVerdasaP3-mHbt6Z6eOJjkOD39mT04QyLvqXDltm0feKeLjDOiHQYmZ1muZO_xa2ywGtQ8b_3EYpv7H1JDczILE1JPsMd9vWzfa8w3-d_Lh7AcSxvk9fkZP0tbCo6LFkGxAUymtE-2aGlg9qMAEABD0QtrYO4J-2iLzhn_dD4uQMoiFUuKiyWu9zfXtybY0W4K-4GBRUhQw6vyVusdHE2wnJfe6hUOdQKs0K9xLpl0ec-0nxrDAQhGK_FcI_aPR2Ks5A8_pNoB6TuLPmAHk7ioy3b_hzGzgEN9wCOJWiuTRZMVTkmtvqpBeAm-mqqcblwHh4g4Yjj-do310UGqLqCFmCsp2FJHtcWvaVrrEMM3yKum7aMW0hm0ogC-yqs52fyvj6ZYJglPkZhLGdbgmFSnYsmm0STRgtOvLFN7foEJSo6ynpjtbeCtvau8pYU3FJvBxbgFCipYdNiHPzVnlHUtuu0cxup7SbpHQL:0C9VzldZJpOglKlrvz0CODU8065CxyxZGpChPcrZMp5D0dqzOhlnYkavuWJhqfxea-7IIw6O5dNL3EIokUcRGJKvKOXKVPcwSJ1MFvqy1WvVXXW4zYi1PRJ3cAeTEX7j1Sn4ekH8O4zxmMHtfz6aLFeXCiI0oxzqvA8-RsFhAVIgWDm1B4JzIZPK38OCEDUIQInQ8WkGEBPFyQsrJdU61VYJWH8q743Jwx8Q1leUgxP7EH7rbW2FFgkGnb8eVmjtIAgjEmwWQzcHjzux4BpKcpwt0irlk:NnOFPU5-I8DVp8Y4iLb340D3JLZoIgxH7iRKiBV12kEViNEXwgriXqaSoFju54hSfm117ywgbJq1W4xmi_gMZU5PHCZ92or7qOxFISP21V1EZC7YW3bArnfiq-1Z0mLNXvvMX6Wms1vLYOkBAtiYpvx_AO_GLLcYf9mKu5yULKhQFeAxIYFYV0sKO-8St2CIbzoUC-yCT-4TCIRbU4Nw_qESZrMTxpMwaN2J4BA4BkwZ5MFefMlcgx6RHQHNYtVZ-MpjpU0Y0Gp9BGwKMcfBmqCsPvrIHMx91SFbFrfefcEJtcTiCw4ta4-OuFhDN-qQFuFQPDYUDIDfDM4WCPN0hGLj2wKqt_4yvDMhBFkNn8w66vJ3RAgowkFW-p3Xhef9NwGMTQgbkfQQ67Jt5C0u97rJb7BchYKf402ASj7ogt-1eLFF52DlDRGJaAwEZjIKqRG5IT6WnkeVIvCBAd1ZwBwPy7j_O56ZPTgZMsMf1nmrX7_BGNEpcVrFH8nzXK30wKVZzSQbXx22CrCFnADjTcXu8kTE6STKoY2t97jYtFgp28JIyaGKxhOjZCn2ifa6u7dYaEAhlPV:3rBKMRqlDYEp1JL-R1zYiY7FtZa4tq7Orz3r82Q-gcO2ZeVR8GX3-p5AavDIHiPBNfdGsH22GhoHfXxrywEZOWY-ZIfWvVxnGjymKxjhjSUDq885YsDFZ1TIpmihiDluSk--C3OKnN9wyyf4rTIdPwv_zZNEyW5ieMOx5Wculq_gsDxRgC98EHhQz6INn853IKEvxjLNwQENmrhCsVSgfzsIUZxzDC4F5_zRCxUcD3-ACTnR38468tQCimme0IFGM1gjsq1GQY_Iqh8czDTwuUjgjgaL5ZxyuiJ-cHgZJ1DhfcZ-JJKdKHpjDjFcThfkCPNvaO-Jg2nYKFGVJ0cBN-CqXlYjZAbl0XEPcGiiZU5YzQGucD4vQRUVogW8tSW-mWApFZPWzEXSD5AO5wibKTVf69ZomGvR96iYh9rCpdlU_eBC56qUyX_8nKyxTAhkaJYGxzCQNXAsW9r7fGnug35e8oI6PeaMwjWrpp1Glzo_Bv2H2vtv1XAxR44bIpV5jEZ60IKUoFItv6TzunxPWQbb2SJe95Bs7ux-w47qm7RK4HoA1Dn14s6cp5YgJuSaYwVyYDkeHJvrKIUNZc6BPptxqHIE32WyJET2Ue4QV9K0wn6X75tpS7TVl69:Yd-ugpfm3a8WosuedaRgvylHqtIIgFN9M2fe9a_TQqMdTvmp16t8SFyAqeHoYKLPaNDrBPz0BwXlpQXJEe9BmzRxtfY8J0HsWxfmRopj9yAtB4ne5SrL8urrT0w-Ki7gnSTSkOAd57cvrBuWuzEKvO1k7iIR4rt_8y2Dt-SN7jYY2YO1vM3RVOiQYLmE8oWyymsU16TTGrYYB6exquAvNvYPM4Wv9kBIUcwltdvwBlCKbtoDCIUDrPa743YnNKMlTLasREtM879nQCyudtvvUJAajM-pGbUDdr0KOLQXsyD0qs3FsAoovWXF1QXuMwwnwjn-VTffl1iNGEWKatvN7mvAbrrcdw_6rQpVQetMSnxfYZ0j3tSKxKmZTeuF_Sf4AFEzrFRsBGwN1qsqg4ot6_WGyLTTyHp40OWxoJjlscaDK3NNByZoUE7JSUla68dDgXV76kjVHtLO78e6CcZ2rPVbaEJFhGNljgNvIhZNDZ37uZsVFWiC7jEVuBjMPlsRS8TML17XrMBQ6rEHaWiCF4jna7SvwspjIP2KA:D5Q52BoKZIICfiZY-jgN3aWudA4"); ?>
```

Any Ideas how I can see the source?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the extension with `.phps`. Some server show the source code of the .php file, even syntax highlighted. If not, you have to adjust the settings of yours.

Comment: you mean just rename the php file? tried but will not show the code. how i adjust the settings to see it?

Comment: Phew, i dont know ... i just tested it here on my dev server and it worked without problems. Guess you have to google for the specific settings.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` function.

Look at the manual:

http://php.net/htmlentities

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php